# Installshield doesn't display the correct language

Tags: windows, localization, internationalization, installshield, installshield-2008

I am using InstallShield 2008 Premier Edition and I have created a multilanguage setup. When I install the setup in language other than English (e.g. in French) it clearly shows all labels and messages correctly.

The problem starts when I run the generated `setup.exe` file again. It should show the Modify/Repair page **in the language that was selected during install** (i.e. in French) but it is always showing in Default Operating Language (English in our case).

However if I click the uninstallation icon on the Start-up menu it is showing in the language which I have installed (i.e. French).

Our requirement is that in both cases it should be same language (i.e. french) but this is not the case.

Comment: Is this an InstallScript-based install, or an MSI install?

Comment: It is InstallScript MSI Project type..

Comment: I tried to make the question clearer, I hope it reflects what you were trying to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried, but maybe you could change the uninstall command to include the parameter to set the language (see http://helpnet.acresso.com/robo/projects/installshield11helplib/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm , look for /L) and add that to the uninstall command that installshield sets up under "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" + PRODUCT_GUID . It does feel a bit hackisch, I'd really expect Installshield to do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the Help..
i will definitely look into this, :))